# Visual Studio 2015 code assist without hotkey

Tags: autocomplete, ide, visual-studio-2015

My VS 2015 doesn't seem to offer code completion unless I use ctrl+space or a period. Is there an option for code assist to auto pop up when you start typing? I already have "auto list members" checked in Text Editor -> All Languages. This is really annoying because I have to use the hotkey every time for syntax keywords and variables.

Thanks

Comment: I think this may be an ongoing issue. VS2015 seems to offer code completion and radomly stop, with only a full restart of VS returning the functionality. I've updated to update 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the intellisense settings at 
Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> IntelliSense

Make sure "Show completion list after a character is typed" is checked.

Comment: I don't see this option for other languages, is it only for C#?

Answer (score 1):

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages (assuming you want that) -> General -> Statement Completion -> check "Auto list members"